# Is it safe to use replacement AC power adapter with a higher Input Amps rating?

Tags: power-supply

I need to replace a damaged AC power adapter for a stair climber with an electronic display and controls.
The original AC adapter is labeled
Input:100-240VAC 50/60Hz **100VA**
Output: 12VDC 5A, Positive Polarity.

A replacement I found is labeled
Input:100-240VAC 50/60Hz **1.5A**
Output: 12VDC 5A, Positive Polarity.

The replacement seems to have about 1/2Amp higher input rating, could this pose a problem for the device or the replacement power adapter?  Or, since the output rating is the same, I shouldn't have any concerns with the slightly higher input Amp rating other than the draw on my electrical circuit breaker?

Is the following statement universally true if all other specs are equal?
"The input rating on a power supply is what it pulls when providing the maximum output rating. In the same way the maximum output of a power supply doesn't mean it must to supply that, the input rating doesn't mean it must to pull that."

Comment: The replacement adapter seems good. Just be sure that the output connector is a proper match - both in polarity and size.

Comment: Please see [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)  *Usage* and *sourcing* questions are generally off-topic, but we have a stock answer for this one.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings is a fantastic reference, but I am focused on the power supply's input Amp rating being different from the OEM.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to worry about the output rating, which seems to match exactly.  This supply may be less efficient, but this is not a major concern unless your AC circuit is already maxed out.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the adapter is only going to draw the amps it needs. So if the original only needed to draw 100VA then the new one will only draw the same 100VA and not need the full 1.5A.